# How to understand Kafka HA?

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I think in a topic with multiple partitions, if one of the partitions is unavailable, the others can still be consumed normally. Is this correct?

If so, why does it report this error when I start the `Spark Streaming` program when one of the partitions is unavailable?

```
Timeout of 60000ms expired before the position for partition [topic_name]-[partition] could be determined
```

[image: some exceptions]

Comment: what is the replication factor of the topic?

Comment: 500+ partitions and replication factor is three.